# How can I get the directory of the offending file from this Java code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I'm trying to locate the directory of the offending font file per these instructions: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-172

I am getting an error with the font name. I have searched and deleted matching files, however, but the script keeps throwing an error on the same font name. I suspect there's a hidden copy somewhere on Windows 7 and I'd like to add file directory information to the output.

Is there a way to obtain directory information about the file prior to the exception output? Or is java using something other than file directory structure to derive the list of fonts in the system?

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

public class FontTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Font[] fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
    for (int i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) {
      final Font font = fonts[i];
      final String name = font.getName();

      System.out.print("Checking Font: " + name);

      if (font.canDisplay('a') &&
        font.canDisplay('z') &&
        font.canDisplay('A') &&
        font.canDisplay('Z') &&
        font.canDisplay('0') &&
        font.canDisplay('1')) {
        System.out.println(" OK.");
      } else {
       System.out.println();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but have you tried rebooting since you deleted the font files?

Comment: Not at all! And yes I have. Several times. Iterating over an array of .getAvailableFontFamilyNames() produces a list of fonts that I may have had installed at one time (I used to do prepress before front-end development) but is not accurate. So either Windows or Java has cached font list data that needs to get flushed and rebuild, but how?

Comment: I think you should post the name of the font, it might help (though I must admit, it is not very likely...). On the flushing and rebuilding part, I think most likely the folks at [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) would be able to help... One question though: how did you get rid of the font files? Did you delete them, or did you uninstall them?

Comment: I figured this out. Windows 7 implements a slick UI for font management. However, this did not display the Adobe Type 1 fonts in the directory. I did a command-line directory inspection and then did a 'search' for one of the files I found. This finally gave me the directory in File Explorer and from there I was able to remove all the Type1 files. PHEW. Thanks!

Comment: I think you should add this as an answer, and accept it, as it solved your problem, and may benefit future visitors of this page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. Windows 7 implements a slick UI for font management. However, this did not display the Adobe Type 1 fonts in the directory. I did a command-line directory inspection and then did a 'search' for one of the files I found. This finally gave me the directory in File Explorer and from there I was able to remove all the Type1 files. PHEW. Thanks!